# Extending Umbraco Contour for encrypt/decrypt of data

Tags: encryption, umbraco, umbraco-contour

I need to encrypt data coming from a set of Contour forms, which i believe i can do by implementing a custom workflow http://our.umbraco.org/projects/umbraco-pro/contour/documentation/Developer/Extending-Contour/Adding-a-Workflowtype

I would then like to use the "Entries" data grid in Contour to show the data that has been submitted in the Umbraco Back office, is there a workflow i can implement to do this? Or an interface i need to implement that Contour will execute before the data is rendered?

Thanks in advance.

Chris

Answer (score 0):

There is a potential answer here, using a custom workflow and adding the decrypt logic to the XSLT in the Contour package that transforms the entries back into the back office.

http://our.umbraco.org/forum/umbraco-pro/contour/49045-Extending-Umbraco-Contour-for-encryptdecrypt-of-data